# AJAX: Check if a string is JSON?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, validation

My JavaScript sometimes crashes on this line:

```
var json = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
```

Crashes are caused when the argument of `eval()` is not JSON. Is there any way to check if the string is JSON before making this call?

I don't want to use a framework - is there any way to make this work using just `eval()`? (There's a good reason, I promise.)

Comment: You could attempt to JSON.parse() in a try/catch... if you get to catch, its not valid JSON markup.  Of course, thats sorta inefficient, heh...  
Could you give me an example of the invalid JSON markup you're getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is a valid JSON string in JavaScript without using Try/Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try)

Answer (score 158):

If you include the [JSON parser](http://www.json.org/js.html) from json.org, you can use its parse() function and just wrap it in a try/catch, like so:

```
try
{
   var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
}
catch(e)
{
   alert('invalid json');
}
```

Something like that would probably do what you want.

Comment: using jQuery.parseJSON(..) you wouldn't need to include json.org

Comment: @Raymo OP didn't mention using jQuery and json2.js less than half the size of jQuery (in terms of file size).

Comment: Parsing an entire string is bad practice, and throwing an exception can cause lag

Comment: it will not throw an exception if you send a number string

Answer (score 22):

Hers's the jQuery alternative...

```
try
{
  var jsonObject = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsonString);
}
catch(e)
{
  // handle error 
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I highly recommend you use a [javascript JSON library](http://www.json.org/js.html) for serializing to and from JSON. `eval()` is a security risk which should never be used unless you are *absolutely certain* that its input is sanitized and safe.

With a JSON library in place, just wrap the call to its `parse()` equivalent in a try/catch-block to handle non-JSON input:

```
try
{
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(yourJsonString);
}
catch(e)
{
  // handle error 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this helps:
With this code, you can get directly your data…

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Open console, please, to view result!</h3>
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var tryJSON = function (test) {
 try {
     JSON.parse(test);
 }
 catch(err) {
     // maybe you need to escape this… (or not)
     test = '"'+test.replace(/\\?"/g,'\\"')+'"';
 }
 eval('test = '+test);
 console.debug('Try json:', test);
};

// test with string…
var test = 'bonjour "mister"';
tryJSON(test);
// test with JSON…
var test = '{"fr-FR": "<p>Ceci est un texte en français !</p>","en-GB": "<p>And here, a text in english!</p>","nl-NL": "","es-ES": ""}';
tryJSON(test);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are a lot of alternative ways to achieve the same result, using eval() is probably be the least appropriate one.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with depending on the `try-catch` approach is that `JSON.parse('123') = 123` and it will not throw an exception. Therefore, In addition to the `try-catch`, we need to check the type as follows:

```
function isJsonStr(str) {
    var parsedStr = str;
    try {
        parsedStr = JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return typeof parsedStr == 'object'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**!!! All other answers are wrong.**

You should be aware of the [http protocol standards](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.2) and follow its rules. That way all developers can **communicate** without even speaking to each other. When you send a request using [AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or any other **http client**, you can use `Accept` **header** to indicate which response content type you accept (expect). And then you use `Content-Type` of the **response** to identify the data format and deal with it accordingly.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/connect/user",
    headers: {          
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" // what we send
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain; charset=utf-8", // what we accept (expect back)
    },
    data: "{ 'field': 'data to be sent' }", 
    success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
        var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
        if (ct.indexOf("text/plain") > -1) {
          // handle text here
        } else if (ct.indexOf("application/json") > -1) {
          // handle json here
        } else {
          throw new Error("Content type " + ct " is not expected/supported.");
        }
    },
    error : function(error) {
        // handle error here
    },
})
```

**Please note** that `Accept` header tells the server what format you accept, so the server can send you the data in the desired format (json, xml, text, html, etc.). Also please be aware that the server [could not support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28478836/response-code-for-accept-type-not-supported) some of the content types, that way you should expect **406** and handle it accordingly. I assume you also handle other [http statuses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) properly.

[screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oKlJE.png)

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery $.ajax()` will add the `responseJSON` property to the response object, and to test if the response is JSON, you can use:

```
if (xhr.hasOwnProperty('responseJSON')) {}
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a tiny library that checks JavaScript types: [is.js](https://github.com/arasatasaygin/is.js)

```
is.json({foo: 'bar'});
=> true

// functions are returning as false
is.json(toString);
=> false

is.not.json([]);
=> true

is.all.json({}, 1);
=> false

is.any.json({}, 2);
=> true

// 'all' and 'any' interfaces can also take array parameter
is.all.json([{}, {foo: 'bar'}]);
=> true
```

Actually [is.js](https://github.com/arasatasaygin/is.js) is much more then this, some honorable mentions:

```
var obj = document.createElement('div');
is.domNode(obj);
=> true

is.error(new Error());
=> true

is.function(toString);
=> true

is.chrome();
=> true if current browser is chrome
```