# How to validate a JSON String JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, validation

I tried that:

```
var c = $.parseJSON(something here)
```

and I control that:

```
c === undefined
```

This works however it throws error while trying to parse an invalid JSON string. I don't want it throw that error.

Any advices?

Comment: is the error halting the execution of your scripts or just complaining about the format?

Comment: check  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313630/ajax-check-if-a-string-is-json     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3945499/how-to-know-if-return-data-is-json-or-string-in-jquery-and-php

Comment: This shouldn't be a duplicate of that question mentioned above. This question asks the Jquery version and the other question is asking for plain javascript. **JQuery and javascript are not the same thing**

Comment: I think so @KolobCanyon.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's generally considered bad practice to suppress/ignore errors, instead why not use a [try-catch block](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_try_catch.asp) to capture the exception and do something with it:

```
try {
  var c = $.parseJSON(something here);
}
catch (err) {
  // Do something about the exception here
}
```

If you really don't need to do anything about the exception at least put a comment to that effect in your `try-catch` block, it'll make your code more readable when you come back to it later.