# How can I check if a value is a JSON object?

Tags: jquery, json, object

My server side code returns a value which is a JSON object on success and a string 'false' on failure. Now how can I check whether the returned value is a JSON object?

Comment: If it's actually "your" server side code, why not have a status field in the JSON result rather than creating this "sometimes-it's-JSON-and-sometimes-it's-not" situation...?

Comment: @Hostile For debugging reasons. You never now which kind of failure the server will throw and at that point json is not being used.

Comment: I still don't see how having an error code (as a named field) in the server response would undermine that.  It's good enough for Freebase!  http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/MQL_errors

Comment: Please change the accepted answer to Serguei Federov's, if you can the currently accepted answer is incorrect.

Comment: What's a "json object"? There's JSON strings and JS objects, but there's no such thing as a "JavaScript Object Notation object".

Comment: @mpen see my answer for details

Comment: @samvv Your answer doesn't address my question. There's no such thing as a "json object". JSON is a *text* format.

Comment: @mpen You're right, I'm sorry. I noticed it too late.

Comment: [There is no such thing as a "JSON Object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation).

Answer (score 114, accepted):

jQuery.parseJSON() should return an object of type "object", if the string was JSON, so you only have to check the type with `typeof`

```
var response=jQuery.parseJSON('response from server');
if(typeof response =='object')
{
  // It is JSON
}
else
{
  if(response ===false)
  {
     // the response was a string "false", parseJSON will convert it to boolean false
  }
  else
  {
    // the response was something else
  }
}
```

Comment: Might also need to use a try / catch for exceptions if it is possible that parseJSON is going to be dealing with something other than JSON values (i.e. HTML)

Comment: Prior to jQuery 1.9, $.parseJSON returned null instead of throwing an error if it was passed an empty string, null, or undefined, even though those are not valid JSON. [jquery site link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)

Comment: This solution is not the best, because return `"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character"` error! , I thinks the best solution is use try/catch that said by `Serguei Fedorov` in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295386/how-can-i-check-if-a-value-is-a-json-object/12217209#12217209

Comment: If you don't want to use jquery, you can use vanilla JS by checking constructor type as described here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11182924/how-to-check-if-javascript-object-is-json

Comment: $.parseJSON expects a well-formed JSON string, and if it doesn't get one, an error is thrown, so this answer won't do it.  You need to use a try/catch, as the answer below suggests.  (Sure would be sweet if jQuery had an "isJSON()" function...)

Comment: @hairbo: The question was about JSON, including a string `"false"`(which is valid JSON too), it wasn't about object-literals, also not about non-well-formed JSON.  Read the question before you downvote an answer!

Comment: @Dr.Molle okay, fair enough. I'd argue that assuming the returned value is either a well-formed JSON string or "false" is not a strong enough test. The server could bomb for unexpected reasons, and you need your client code to handle that condition, hence the desire for an "isJSON()" function.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, the answer by Serguei Federov should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The reason that I'm vote down this answer is becasuse is wrong first parse and then validate if this is a objetc type of. How you can parse nothing if your are returning anything or an empty string or json from your server? This is wrong and this answer is not usefull.

Comment: @Fernando Urban: how would you work with the response without parsing it? In any case the response will be a string before it will be parsed

Comment: No. If your are working with a set time out in javascript that recieves each minute any answer from the server but this depends like an "echo json_encode($value)" that have an IF ELSE statement and if is any boolean true result this will return  a json_encode but if this is false this will return nothing. So, how you can parse nothing if you are no returning anything even you can return something but you still not wanting return something?

Comment: I this case, you have to try and catch the JSON, like the answer below

Comment: Maybe I repeat myself, but when you read the question once more you will recognize  that the response is always **valid JSON** ....no need to try/catch anything

Comment: I know this thread is more than a year old, but if it's always a valid JSON, then why even bother to check?

Comment: People really need to quit answering Javascript questions with jQuery without providing a jquery-less alternative. Many JS environments are not compatible with jQuery.

Comment: @liljoshu : maybe you didn't notice that the question has been tagged with `jquery` by the author ?

Answer (score 156):

[The chosen solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4295670/662581) doesn't actually work for me because I get a

```
     "Unexpected Token <"
```

error in Chrome. This is because the error is thrown as soon as the parse comes across and unknown character. However, there is a way around this if you are returning only string values through ajax (which can be fairly useful if you are using PHP or ASPX to process ajax requests and might or might not return JSON depending on conditions)

The solution is quite simple, you can do the following to check if it was a valid JSON return

```
       var IS_JSON = true;
       try
       {
               var json = $.parseJSON(msg);
       }
       catch(err)
       {
               IS_JSON = false;
       }
```

As I have said before, this is the solution for if you are either returning string type stuff from your AJAX request or if you are returning mixed type.

Comment: The question isn't about non-JSON-strings in any point. The server returns **always** a valid JSON (a string `false` is also valid JSON). The question is only about a single point: how to differentiate if the parsed JSON-string is a boolean `false` or an object

Comment: Performance consideration: Wrapping this in a function, make sure to not parse the json twice (once inside the try catch, and once in the code that calls the function.)

Comment: It's a helpers function [isJSON()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31508686/2578107) that you can use: ```isJSON(someValue)```.

Answer (score 26):

#### Solution 3 (fastest way)

```
/**
 * @param Object
 * @returns boolean
 */
function isJSON (something) {
    if (typeof something != 'string')
        something = JSON.stringify(something);

    try {
        JSON.parse(something);
        return true;
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use it:

```
var myJson = [{"user":"chofoteddy"}, {"user":"bart"}];
isJSON(myJson); // true
```

---

The best way to validate that an object is of type JSON or array is as follows:

```
var a = [],
    o = {};
```

#### Solution 1

```
toString.call(o) === '[object Object]'; // true
toString.call(a) === '[object Array]'; // true
```

#### Solution 2

```
a.constructor.name === 'Array'; // true
o.constructor.name === 'Object'; // true
```

But, strictly speaking, an array is part of a JSON syntax. Therefore, the following two examples are part of a JSON response:

```
console.log(response); // {"message": "success"}
console.log(response); // {"user": "bart", "id":3}
```

And:

```
console.log(response); // [{"user":"chofoteddy"}, {"user":"bart"}]
console.log(response); // ["chofoteddy", "bart"]
```

---

#### AJAX / JQuery (recommended)

If you use JQuery to bring information via AJAX. I recommend you put in the "dataType" attribute the "json" value, that way if you get a JSON or not, JQuery validate it for you and make it known through their functions "success" and "error". Example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.something.com',
    data: $('#formId').serialize(),
    method: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    // "sucess" will be executed only if the response status is 200 and get a JSON
    success: function (json) {},
    // "error" will run but receive state 200, but if you miss the JSON syntax
    error: function (xhr) {}
});
```

Answer (score 14):

If you have jQuery, use [isPlainObject](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isPlainObject/).

```
if ($.isPlainObject(my_var)) {}
```

Comment: If you use isPlainObject on a string it return false, e.g. jQuery.isPlainObject('{}')

Comment: More importantly, if it contains a non-JSON-like value as a property, according to the docs this function will still return `true`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var checkJSON = function(m) {

   if (typeof m == 'object') { 
      try{ m = JSON.stringify(m); }
      catch(err) { return false; } }

   if (typeof m == 'string') {
      try{ m = JSON.parse(m); }
      catch (err) { return false; } }

   if (typeof m != 'object') { return false; }
   return true;

};


checkJSON(JSON.parse('{}'));      //true
checkJSON(JSON.parse('{"a":0}')); //true
checkJSON('{}');                  //true
checkJSON('{"a":0}');             //true
checkJSON('x');                   //false
checkJSON('');                    //false
checkJSON();                      //false
```

Answer (score 4):

Since it's just false and json object, why don't you check whether it's false, otherwise it must be json.

```
if(ret == false || ret == "false") {
    // json
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread has been answered already, but coming here didn't really solve my problems, I found this function somewhere else.
maybe someone coming here will find it to be of some use to them;

```
function getClass(obj) {
  if (typeof obj === "undefined")
    return "undefined";
  if (obj === null)
    return "null";
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj)
    .match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = 'json string ?';
var jdata = null;
try
{
    jdata = $.parseJSON(data);  
}catch(e)
{}

if(jdata)
{
//use jdata
}else
{
//use data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test explicitly for valid JSON (as opposed to the absence of the returned value `false`), then you can use a parsing approach as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try-c).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really like the accepted answer. First and foremost it requires jQuery, which is not always available or required. Secondly, it does a full stringification of the object which to me is overkill. Here's a simple function that thoroughly detects whether a value is JSON-like, using nothing more than a few parts of the [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library for genericity.

```
import * as isNull from 'lodash/isNull'
import * as isPlainObject from 'lodash/isPlainObject'
import * as isNumber from 'lodash/isNumber'
import * as isBoolean from 'lodash/isBoolean'
import * as isString from 'lodash/isString'
import * as isArray from 'lodash/isArray'

function isJSON(val) {
  if (isNull(val)
   || isBoolean(val)
   || isString(val))
    return true;
  if (isNumber(val)) 
     return !isNaN(val) && isFinite(val)
  if (isArray(val))
    return Array.prototype.every.call(val, isJSON)
  if (isPlainObject(val)) {
    for (const key of Object.keys(val)) {
      if (!isJSON(val[key]))
        return false
    }
    return true
  }
  return false
}
```

I've even taken the time to put it up in npm as a package: https://npmjs.com/package/is-json-object. Use it together with something like [Webpack](https://lodash.com/) to get it in the browser.

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 0):

**I am using this to validate JSON Object**

```
function isJsonObject(obj) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**I am using this to validate JSON String**

```
function isJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried all of the suggested answers, nothing worked for me, so i had to use

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject()
```

hoe that helps someone else out with this issue

Answer (score -1):

You should return json **always**, but change its **status**, or in following example the **ResponseCode** property:

```
if(callbackResults.ResponseCode!="200"){
    /* Some error, you can add a message too */
} else {
    /* All fine, proceed with code */
};
```

Comment: @bart , you can just provide the object in the if condition , that will do the check.