# How to check if JavaScript object is JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have a nested JSON object that I need to loop through, and the value of each key could be a String, JSON array or another JSON object. Depending on the type of object, I need to carry out different operations. Is there any way I can check the type of the object to see if it is a String, JSON object or JSON array?

I tried using `typeof` and `instanceof` but both didn't seem to work, as `typeof` will return an object for both JSON object and array, and `instanceof` gives an error when I do `obj instanceof JSON`.

To be more specific, after parsing the JSON into a JS object, is there any way I can check if it is a normal string, or an object with keys and values (from a JSON object), or an array (from a JSON array)?

For example:

JSON

```
var data = "{'hi':
             {'hello':
               ['hi1','hi2']
             },
            'hey':'words'
           }";
```

Sample JavaScript

```
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
var path = ["hi","hello"];

function check(jsonObj, path) {
    var parent = jsonObj;
    for (var i = 0; i < path.length-1; i++) {
        var key = path[i];
        if (parent != undefined) {
            parent = parent[key];
        }
    }
    if (parent != undefined) {
        var endLength = path.length - 1;
        var child = parent[path[endLength]];
        //if child is a string, add some text
        //if child is an object, edit the key/value
        //if child is an array, add a new element
        //if child does not exist, add a new key/value
    }
}
```

How do I carry out the object checking as shown above?

Comment: [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is just a notation stored as a *string*. Are you sure you're not confusing terms?

Comment: Nope, I updated the question to make it clearer. I guess my main question is what happens after we do a `.parse()` on a JSON string, and how to identify it?

Comment: change hasn't made it more clear (at leas for me). What if you give example of JSON you're dealing with

Comment: Updated question with an example. (:

Comment: The real question is: why do you care?

Comment: You cannot know if "level1 was formerly a JSON object". You can only know it is an object *now*.

Comment: @Len: Because based on what it originally was, I need to carry out different operations.

Comment: Your talk of what the object was formerly confuses me. Before you parsed the data, jsonObj.level1 didn't exist. After you parsed it's an object.

Comment: @PeterWilkinson: Ok, it seems that my question is still confusing. I've edited the question again. Hope it helps.

Comment: @WeiHao The whatIsIt method I suggested below should work nicely for you.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

I'd check the constructor attribute.

e.g.

```
var stringConstructor = "test".constructor;
var arrayConstructor = [].constructor;
var objectConstructor = ({}).constructor;

function whatIsIt(object) {
    if (object === null) {
        return "null";
    }
    if (object === undefined) {
        return "undefined";
    }
    if (object.constructor === stringConstructor) {
        return "String";
    }
    if (object.constructor === arrayConstructor) {
        return "Array";
    }
    if (object.constructor === objectConstructor) {
        return "Object";
    }
    {
        return "don't know";
    }
}

var testSubjects = ["string", [1,2,3], {foo: "bar"}, 4];

for (var i=0, len = testSubjects.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert(whatIsIt(testSubjects[i]));
}
```

Edit: Added a null check and an undefined check.

Comment: `else if` is unnecessary

Comment: Is not this the same as using instanceof?
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Comment: @Pereira: JavaScript has some confusing wrinkles.  Try "surely_this_is_a_string" instanceof String.

Comment: `{}.constructor` is causing me to get `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined` in my angular application.

Comment: @Minyc510 : Looks like browser behaviour has changed.  Wrapping in brackets seems to fix it.  I've edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: So many `if` statements... Use a [`switch`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)!

Comment: Nice answer - but absolutely ridiculous that there is no function to do this in JS

Comment: I don't feel that this answers the question. a string is a string, but a JSON object is ... also a string. So in my case, I need to check if any value is JSON before I call JSON.parse, so it doesn't blow up.

My answer would be to use try-catch and just return false in the catch and true otherwise.

Comment: The question has been edited a few times, but the last paragraph still specifically requests determining object type after it has been parsed.

Answer (score 35):

You can use **Array.isArray** to check for arrays.  Then **typeof obj == 'string'**, and **typeof obj == 'object'**.

```
var s = 'a string', a = [], o = {}, i = 5;
function getType(p) {
    if (Array.isArray(p)) return 'array';
    else if (typeof p == 'string') return 'string';
    else if (p != null && typeof p == 'object') return 'object';
    else return 'other';
}
console.log("'s' is " + getType(s));
console.log("'a' is " + getType(a));
console.log("'o' is " + getType(o));
console.log("'i' is " + getType(i));
```

> 's' is string
> 'a' is array
>  'o' is object
> 'i' is other

Comment: Don't forget to take into account that `typeof null === 'object'`

Comment: `[{
  "name":[
    {"key": "any key" }   
    ]
}]` 

this  is also valid json but its return array by your code.
check this - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dhjbtuw/14/)

Comment: If you ̵d̵a̵r̵e̵ ̵t̵o̵ use that function for a `class Test {}`, `typeof` will return `object`, sooo...

Answer (score 27):

An JSON object **is** an object. To check whether a type is an object type, evaluate the constructor property.

```
function isObject(obj)
{
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && obj.constructor == Object;
}
```

The same applies to all other types:

```
function isArray(obj)
{
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && obj.constructor == Array;
}

function isBoolean(obj)
{
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && obj.constructor == Boolean;
}

function isFunction(obj)
{
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && obj.constructor == Function;
}

function isNumber(obj)
{
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && obj.constructor == Number;
}

function isString(obj)
{
    return obj !== undefined && obj !== null && obj.constructor == String;
}

function isInstanced(obj)
{
    if(obj === undefined || obj === null) { return false; }

    if(isArray(obj)) { return false; }
    if(isBoolean(obj)) { return false; }
    if(isFunction(obj)) { return false; }
    if(isNumber(obj)) { return false; }
    if(isObject(obj)) { return false; }
    if(isString(obj)) { return false; }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: JSON encoded resource is not an object.  It is a string.  Only after you decode it or in Javascript `JSON.parse()` it does the JSON resource become an object.  Therefore if you test a resource coming from a server to see if it is JSON, it is best to check first for String, then if is a not a `<empty string>` and then after parsing if it is an object.

Comment: This is easiest way! Worked

Answer (score 10):

you can also try to parse the data and then check if you got object:

```
try {
    var testIfJson = JSON.parse(data);
    if (typeof testIfJson == "object"){
        //Json
    } else {
        //Not Json
    }
}
catch {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This can cause an "Uncaught SyntaxError" if the data isn't JSON parsable

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to check the type of an `object` after you parse a `JSON` string, I suggest checking the constructor attribute:

```
obj.constructor == Array || obj.constructor == String || obj.constructor == Object
```

This will be a much faster check than typeof or instanceof.

If a **JSON library** does not return objects constructed with these functions, I would be very suspiciouse of it.

Comment: A much more direct approach. Thanks! =D

Comment: Preferred answer. Where do you get the performance benefit info from?

Comment: @DanielF it was common wisdom back in ‘12, things are all different now so I don’t know if that holds

Answer (score 8):

The answer by @PeterWilkinson didn't work for me because a constructor for a "typed" object is customized to the name of that object. I had to work with [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)

```js
function isJson(obj) {
    var t = typeof obj;
    return ['boolean', 'number', 'string', 'symbol', 'function'].indexOf(t) == -1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You could make your own constructor for JSON parsing:

```
var JSONObj = function(obj) { $.extend(this, JSON.parse(obj)); }
var test = new JSONObj('{"a": "apple"}');
//{a: "apple"}
```

Then check instanceof to see if it needed parsing originally

```
test instanceof JSONObj
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote an npm module to solve this problem. It's available [here](https://github.com/dawsonbotsford/object-types):

`object-types`: a module for finding what literal types underly objects

### Install

```
  npm install --save object-types
```

### Usage

```
const objectTypes = require('object-types');

objectTypes({});
//=> 'object'

objectTypes([]);
//=> 'array'

objectTypes(new Object(true));
//=> 'boolean'
```

Take a look, it should solve your exact problem. Let me know if you have any questions! https://github.com/dawsonbotsford/object-types

Answer (score 4):

Try, Catch block will help you to solve this

**Make a function**

```js
function IsJson(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Example:**

```js
console.log(IsJson('abc')) // false
console.log(IsJson('[{"type":"email","detail":"john@example.com"}]')) // true
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not check Number - a bit shorter and works in IE/Chrome/FF/node.js

```js
function whatIsIt(object) {
    if (object === null) {
        return "null";
    }
    else if (object === undefined) {
        return "undefined";
    }
    if (object.constructor.name) {
            return object.constructor.name;
    }
    else { // last chance 4 IE: "\nfunction Number() {\n    [native code]\n}\n" / node.js: "function String() { [native code] }"
        var name = object.constructor.toString().split(' ');
        if (name && name.length > 1) {
            name = name[1];
            return name.substr(0, name.indexOf('('));
        }
        else { // unreachable now(?)
            return "don't know";
        }
    }
}

var testSubjects = ["string", [1,2,3], {foo: "bar"}, 4];
// Test all options
console.log(whatIsIt(null));
console.log(whatIsIt());
for (var i=0, len = testSubjects.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(whatIsIt(testSubjects[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I combine the typeof operator with a check of the constructor attribute (by Peter):

```
var typeOf = function(object) {
    var firstShot = typeof object;
    if (firstShot !== 'object') {
        return firstShot;
    } 
    else if (object.constructor === [].constructor) {
        return 'array';
    }
    else if (object.constructor === {}.constructor) {
        return 'object';
    }
    else if (object === null) {
        return 'null';
    }
    else {
        return 'don\'t know';
    } 
}

// Test
var testSubjects = [true, false, 1, 2.3, 'string', [4,5,6], {foo: 'bar'}, null, undefined];

console.log(['typeOf()', 'input parameter'].join('\t'))
console.log(new Array(28).join('-'));
testSubjects.map(function(testSubject){
    console.log([typeOf(testSubject), JSON.stringify(testSubject)].join('\t\t'));
});
```

Result:

```
typeOf()    input parameter
---------------------------
boolean     true
boolean     false
number      1
number      2.3
string      "string"
array       [4,5,6]
object      {"foo":"bar"}
null        null
undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old question with good answers. However, it seems that it's still possible to add my 2¢ to it.

Assuming that you're trying to test not a JSON object itself but a String that is formatted as a JSON (which seems to be the case in your `var data`), you could use the following function that returns a boolean (is or is not a 'JSON'):

```
function isJsonString( jsonString ) {

  // This function below ('printError') can be used to print details about the error, if any.
  // Please, refer to the original article (see the end of this post)
  // for more details. I suppressed details to keep the code clean.
  //
  let printError = function(error, explicit) {
  console.log(`[${explicit ? 'EXPLICIT' : 'INEXPLICIT'}] ${error.name}: ${error.message}`);
  }


  try {
      JSON.parse( jsonString );
      return true; // It's a valid JSON format
  } catch (e) {
      return false; // It's not a valid JSON format
  }

}
```

Here are some examples of using the function above:

```
console.log('\n1 -----------------');
let j = "abc";
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n2 -----------------');
j = `{"abc": "def"}`;
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n3 -----------------');
j = '{"abc": "def}';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n4 -----------------');
j = '{}';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n5 -----------------');
j = '[{}]';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n6 -----------------');
j = '[{},]';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n7 -----------------');
j = '[{"a":1, "b":   2}, {"c":3}]';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );
```

When you run the code above, you will get the following results:

```
1 -----------------
abc false

2 -----------------
{"abc": "def"} true

3 -----------------
{"abc": "def} false

4 -----------------
{} true

5 -----------------
[{}] true

6 -----------------
[{},] false

7 -----------------
[{"a":1, "b":   2}, {"c":3}] true
```

Please, try the snippet below and let us know if this works for you. :)

IMPORTANT: the function presented in this post was adapted from https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/syntaxerror-json-parse-bad-parsing where you can find more and interesting details about the JSON.parse() function.

```js
function isJsonString( jsonString ) {

  let printError = function(error, explicit) {
  console.log(`[${explicit ? 'EXPLICIT' : 'INEXPLICIT'}] ${error.name}: ${error.message}`);
  }


  try {
      JSON.parse( jsonString );
      return true; // It's a valid JSON format
  } catch (e) {
      return false; // It's not a valid JSON format
  }

}


console.log('\n1 -----------------');
let j = "abc";
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n2 -----------------');
j = `{"abc": "def"}`;
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n3 -----------------');
j = '{"abc": "def}';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n4 -----------------');
j = '{}';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n5 -----------------');
j = '[{}]';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n6 -----------------');
j = '[{},]';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );

console.log('\n7 -----------------');
j = '[{"a":1, "b":   2}, {"c":3}]';
console.log( j, isJsonString(j) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ( typeof is_json != "function" )
function is_json( _obj )
{
    var _has_keys = 0 ;
    for( var _pr in _obj )
    {
        if ( _obj.hasOwnProperty( _pr ) && !( /^\d+$/.test( _pr ) ) )
        {
           _has_keys = 1 ;
           break ;
        }
    }

    return ( _has_keys && _obj.constructor == Object && _obj.constructor != Array ) ? 1 : 0 ;
}
```

It works for the example below

```
var _a = { "name" : "me",
       "surname" : "I",
       "nickname" : {
                      "first" : "wow",
                      "second" : "super",
                      "morelevel" : {
                                      "3level1" : 1,
                                      "3level2" : 2,
                                      "3level3" : 3
                                    }
                    }
     } ;

var _b = [ "name", "surname", "nickname" ] ;
var _c = "abcdefg" ;

console.log( is_json( _a ) );
console.log( is_json( _b ) );
console.log( is_json( _c ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Martin Wantke answer, but with some recommended improvements/adjusts...

```
// NOTE: Check JavaScript type. By Questor
function getJSType(valToChk) {

    function isUndefined(valToChk) { return valToChk === undefined; }
    function isNull(valToChk) { return valToChk === null; }
    function isArray(valToChk) { return valToChk.constructor == Array; }
    function isBoolean(valToChk) { return valToChk.constructor == Boolean; }
    function isFunction(valToChk) { return valToChk.constructor == Function; }
    function isNumber(valToChk) { return valToChk.constructor == Number; }
    function isString(valToChk) { return valToChk.constructor == String; }
    function isObject(valToChk) { return valToChk.constructor == Object; }

    if(isUndefined(valToChk)) { return "undefined"; }
    if(isNull(valToChk)) { return "null"; }
    if(isArray(valToChk)) { return "array"; }
    if(isBoolean(valToChk)) { return "boolean"; }
    if(isFunction(valToChk)) { return "function"; }
    if(isNumber(valToChk)) { return "number"; }
    if(isString(valToChk)) { return "string"; }
    if(isObject(valToChk)) { return "object"; }

}
```

**NOTE:** I found this approach very didactic, so I submitted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Peter's answer with an additional check! Of course, not 100% guaranteed!

```
var isJson = false;
outPutValue = ""
var objectConstructor = {}.constructor;
if(jsonToCheck.constructor === objectConstructor){
    outPutValue = JSON.stringify(jsonToCheck);
    try{
            JSON.parse(outPutValue);
            isJson = true;
    }catch(err){
            isJson = false;
    }
}

if(isJson){
    alert("Is json |" + JSON.stringify(jsonToCheck) + "|");
}else{
    alert("Is other!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a pretty lazy answer to this, which will not throw an error if you try to parse a string/other values.

```
const checkForJson = (value) => {
    if (typeof value !== "string") return false;

    return value[0] === "{" && value[value.length - 1] === "}";
}
```

You can use this to check the value of your keys while you make some recursive func; sorry if this doesn't answer the question completely

Ofc this isn't the most elegant solution and will fail when a string actually starts with "{" and ends with "}" although those use cases would be rare, and if you really wanted, you can check for a presence of quotes or other nonsense... anyway, use at your own discretion.

TLDR: it's not bulletproof, but it's simple and works for the vast majority of use cases.

Comment: It will also not work if there is an array inside. Try with `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(['a','b','c',1,2,3])))`

Answer (score 0):

**lodash** is also the best bet to check these things.

```js
function Foo() {
  this.a = 1;
}
 
_.isPlainObject(new Foo);
// => false
 
_.isPlainObject([1, 2, 3]);
// => false
 
_.isPlainObject({ 'x': 0, 'y': 0 });
// => true
 
_.isPlainObject(Object.create(null));
// => true
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash 
https://lodash.com/docs/#isPlainObject

Answer (score 0):

Quickly check for a JSON structure using [lodash-contrib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-contrib):

```
const _ = require('lodash-contrib');

_.isJSON('{"car": "ferarri"}'); //true for stringified
_.isJSON({car: "ferarri"}); //true
```

Usage guide: [this blog entry](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lodash-_-isjson-method/#:%7E:text=The%20Lodash%20_.,returns%20the%20corresponding%20boolean%20value.)

Answer (score -5):

try this dirty way

```
 ('' + obj).includes('{')
```