# What's the difference between this two javascript objects

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get values from the following object. The for loop works in one of the objects but won't in the other javascript object. I was wondering what the difference and how can I get it to work in the other object?

Object 1:

```
var objects = [
  {
    "foo" : "bar",
    "bar" : "sit"
  },
  {
    "foo" : "lorem",
    "bar" : "ipsum"
  }
];
```

Object 2:

```
{
"4dd5a49e366": {
"name" : "bar",
"bar" : "sit",
"date": "2016-08-03T04:48:04.283Z"
},
"519c5056af2": {
"name" : "lorem",
"bar" : "ipsum",
"date": "2016-09-03T04:48:04.283Z"
}
}
```

I want to do a search for items where name attribute is matching some search_term. And return the items.

Here is the search for loops am using.

```
function searchFor(toSearch) {
      var results = [];
      toSearch = trimString(toSearch); // trim it
      for(var i=0; i<objects.length; i++) {
        for(var i in objects[i]) {
          if(objects[i][key].indexOf(toSearch)!=-1) {
            if(!itemExists(results, objects[i])) results.push(objects[i]);
          }
        }
      }
      return results;
    }
   console.log(searchFor('o'));
```

This works for the first object and not for the second. How can I get it to work for the second?

Comment: That is because 1 is an array and 2 is an object. Note the difference between the square brackets and curly brackets.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/11183002/643500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first variable is an array of objects. Since it is an array you can use all array methods on it.

Second one is an object with keys `4dd5a49e366` & `519c5056af2` which in turn are again object and have few properties.

You cannot use array methods on this second object

> how can I get it to work in the other object?

Hope this snippet will be useful

```
var myObject = {
  "4dd5a49e366": {
    "name": "bar",
    "bar": "sit",
    "date": "2016-08-03T04:48:04.283Z"
  },
  "519c5056af2": {
    "name": "lorem",
    "bar": "ipsum",
    "date": "2016-09-03T04:48:04.283Z"
  }
}
// a function to accept the name value
function findByName(name) {
  var thisObject = "";
  for (var keys in myObject) { // looping over objects
    var getThisObject = myObject[keys];
    if (getThisObject.name === name) { // Checking if name matches
      thisObject = myObject[keys]; // assigning the object to a variable
    }
  }
  return thisObject // return that variable
}
var getMyObject = findByName('bar');
console.log(getMyObject)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d2hh1ezq/)

**EDIT**

> if I enter just findByName('b'); it should return results that the
>   full name

You need to use `indexOf` to find if this name value contains the specific character.

Use an array to store all the relevant object where the name value contains this specific character.Return that array from the function.

```
function findByName(name) {
  var thisObject = [];
  for (var keys in myObject) {
    var getThisObject = myObject[keys];
    if (getThisObject.name.indexOf(name)!==-1) {
      thisObject.push(myObject[keys]);
    }
  }
  return thisObject
}
var getMyObject = findByName('b');
```

[**JSFIDDLE 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/d2hh1ezq/2/)

Comment: And by the way am doing a search for some letters in name that match the search term. So for example... if I enter just findByName('b'); it should return results that the full name findByName('bar') will.

Comment: you didn't mentioned it in your question

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I will really be grateful if I can get that to work.

Comment: ok so what will happen when there are multiple name which has `b` in them.

Comment: It should return all the items having b.

Comment: you mean to say it will only return the name or the object which contain the name? & if it is only name then how it will be returned in an array or as a concatenated string?

Comment: The object so that I can get the other elements like "Bar" and "date"

Comment: This is case sensitive as indexOf is . Is there any work around beside using .toLowerCase()

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do some reading on JavaScript Object literals and Arrays. The first example is an array of objects. The second is just an object. Two completely different data structures.