# Is that possible to get data from an API automatically recognized as JSON with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, json, api

I'd like to consume an API (Python Django) that produce data under 'String' JSON format.

Is there an option to recognize it automatically as a JavaScript object with JQuery?

Comment: If you can use JSONP, that will solve it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887209/what-are-the-differences-between-json-and-jsonp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) please follow the link for full details.

I'm assuming here, that you are getting a proper JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your definition of "automatically". If you mean you want the code to interpret the response as JSON without explicitly telling the code to interpret the response as JSON, then the answer is no.

What you probably want to do is abstract ajax into a function that makes the assumptions you want to make.

Comment: I meant from the API call, recognized directly as a JavaScript 'object'

Comment: @awzx Why not just use `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: JSON.parse() will throw an error if API doesn't provide JSON content

Comment: @awzx You can catch it like so. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4295670/3774582. You want to receive and interpret json, you have to tell the code to do so. There's nothing magical. Are you saying the api provides normal string, and you want to CONVERT it to a json?

Comment: In this case, JQuery.parseJSON() when receiving the data seems the safest as it'll handling the errors by itself.

Comment: @awzx so does parseJSON() answer your question?

Comment: Yes ! Among the different possible approach, that's the one I prefer.

Answer (score 0):

if your json string as below

> '{"a":0,"b":"text"}'

only with JS native

```js
var _string = '{"a":0,"b":"text"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(_string));
```