# How to check in node.js if variable is JSON object?

Tags: json, node.js

I have variable for example

```
var x = "this is X value";
```

How to check in node.js if variable is JSON object ?

Comment: If you expect JSON input, you should use `JSON.parse`. Surround it will `try { ... } catch { ... }`. If there is an exception, it was not valid JSON input.

Comment: I'm curious - why was the try/catch approach not an option?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Your question is not clear, but assuming you meant to check if a variable has an unparsed JSON string:

```
try {
    JSON.parse(x);
} catch (e) {
    console.log("not JSON");
}
```

Comment: thank you, I find here the answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try

Comment: this will not work if the string is a number, like JSON.parse(11) is 11 , no errors