# Stripe Checkout PHP API getting 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Here is my situation, i'm implementing Custom Stripe Checkout with Stripe PHP Api.

I have requested a post Method using jquery like this one >

```js
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_yGQM97VuEUdttuOOFQcyaPHW',
    image: 'https://stripe.com/img/documentation/checkout/marketplace.png',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function (token) {
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
        $.post(
                'charge.php',
                {
                    sT: token.id,
                    sE: token.email
                }, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
        }
        );
    }
});

var thePayment = document.getElementById('pay-amount');

if (thePayment) {
    thePayment.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
        var desc = $('#pay-amount').attr('data-desc');
        var amount = Number($('#pay-amount').attr('data-amount'));
        var email = $('#pay-amount').attr('data-email');
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        handler.open({
            name: 'Test',
            description: desc,
            amount: amount,
            email: email,
            allowRememberMe: false
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
// Close Checkout on page navigation:
window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
    handler.close();
});
```

And the PHP side is just like this one >

```
require_once('html/includes/vendor/autoload.php');

$stripe = array(
    "secret_key" => "sk_test_nJxSc9Yw716tLBWTa9HHMxhj",
    "publishable_key" => "pk_test_yGQM97VuEUdttuOOFQcyaPHW"
);

$charge_reply = array();

\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $token = $_POST['sT'];
    $email = $_POST['sE'];

    $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                'email' => $email,
                'source' => $token
    ));
    $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                "amount" => 1000,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $customer->id,
                "email" => $email,
                "description" => "Example charge"
    ));

    $charge_reply[] = [
        'token' => $token,
        'email' => $email
    ];

    sendJson($charge_reply);
    return;
}
```

I have also enabled the curl,json,mbstring in php. But the function that accepts after requesting a post method to the charge.php, prints `POST http://example.com/charge.php 500 (Internal Server Error)` in the console log.

So is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: If your own code triggers a 500 error, have a look at the error log to find the cause

Comment: Yes i did, but because it's huge and compex api, i couldn't understand it easily, matter of fact it should have worked, because i just do it just like what the documentation said.

Comment: So, you just ignore the error log? That's a bad idea. What does it contain?

Answer (score 4):

500 (Internal Server Error) is something wrong in your code which means their is a fatal error.

To find the error you should use below code in your top of the page.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

It will return the exact error so can fix it.

Note: Do not use it in production environment this for your local development.

Comment: Thanks Dude, but i have found an Error reply saying `Fatal error:  Uncaught Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest: No such token`. Which i haven't made any error sending the token from the client side. I have also search about this error, they advised to refresh the public key, i did it, but not luck there.

Comment: I think the PHP seems okay did you checked the token which you got from front end (jQuery). Check it my doubt is it may return empty or encoded data.

Comment: @Ram Your 2 lines of code solved my problem after I'd spent literally 5 hours trying every other possible solution! It gave me the exact error that my `.php` file was throwing (viewable in the Network-->Response tab in the browser dev tools) Thank you