# Can JSON.parse() indicate a valid JSON format?

Tags: javascript, json

For a long time I used `try - catch` to be sure that a string is a valid JSON. Today I found that `JSON.parse(1)` (a number) returns `1` and `JSON.parse("123")` returns `"123"` while I expect a syntax error like: `Expecting '{', '['`.

Even [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710506/1420197) doesn't seem to solve my problem.

So, the question is: can JSON.parse() indicate if the argument that I pass there has a correct JSON format or not?

If not, which is the alternative?

Comment: Why not just attempt to parse it like the second answer on that link and capture the error?

Comment: @Lloyd No, because no error is thrown...

Comment: @Lloyd (see the question edit) I expect (as you) an **error** but it returns a number or a string.

Comment: I get a `JSON.parse: Unable to parse value: string` Error from that, as one should. But it is known that there are EcmaScript implementations that do not handle passed primitives correctly.

Comment: a valid JSON can be null or true or false or JSONNumber or JSONString or JSONObject or JSONArray. 1(JSONNumber) and "string"(JSONString) are valid json.

Comment: @Bergi You are correct. But if the string can be converted in number the error disappears.

Comment: @MoazzamKhan Why http://jsonlint.org/ doesn't say same thing?

Comment: @Johnツ: That's because it is a valid JSONValue, what [JSON.parse](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.2) parses. JSONLint does expect complete [JSON-texts](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt). If you need that, just check whether your result is `typeof` object.

Comment: `JSON.parse` is not a JSON validator. It is suppose to parse valid JSON in an efficient manner, that does not mean it should not parse some invalid cases.

Comment: @Johnツ see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON)

Comment: @Vatev That sounds interesting. Which would be the alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The grammar given in [ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) *15.12.1.2 - The JSON Syntactic Grammar* states:

```
JSONText :
  JSONValue

JSONValue :
  JSONNullLiteral
  JSONBooleanLiteral
  JSONObject
  JSONArray
  JSONString
  JSONNumber
```

Therefore plain primitive type values are actually valid JSON. Your expectation that only arrays and complex objects are valid JSON is wrong.

`JSON.parse(1)` will be coerced to a string, so it is equivalent to `JSON.parse("1")`. And `1` is a valid `JSONValue` and therefore a valid `JSONText` resulting in the the parser just returning `1` again. Same with `JSON.parse("123")`.

The ECMA-262 grammar seems to differ from the one given in [RFC 4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), but expect browsers to follow ECMA rather than the RFC.

PS: You may still validate further with something like:

```
var v = JSON.parse(jsonString);
if (v !== new Object(v)) { // Also: works when v = null
  throw new Error("Not an Object/Array");
}
```

Comment: The [official RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says `JSON-text = object / array`. His expectation is not wrong, it only does not apply to EcmaScript's `JSON.parse` behaviour.

Comment: @Bergi, you're right, the RFC has a different grammar. So his expectation is wrong only in regards to implementations of the ECMA spec, e.g. browsers.

Comment: @nmaier Good! This is what I want! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Can JSON.parse() indicate if the argument that I pass there has a correct JSON format or not?

Yes, that's what it does. Only there are two different definitions of "*correct*". While the [official RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) says `JSON-text = object / array`, the [EcmaScript JSON Grammar](http://es5.github.io/#x15.12.1.2) is more liberal and considers every `JSONValue` to be a `JSONText`. `JSON.parse` does work as expected.

If you want to restrict the accepted values to object and array notations, simply use

```
var result = JSON.parse(string);
if (result !== Object(result)) // typeof result != 'object' || result == null
    throw new Error("JSON.parse: Object or Array literal expected, got: "+typeof result);
```

Comment: +1, as you beat me to the `result !== Object(result)` stuff. :)