# How to catch this error NodeJs/Express?

Tags: ajax, json, node.js, express

I'm trying to write simple web service using NodeJs. I make Ajax call as below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:3800",

    // this json below is invalid and I need to verify it on server side
    data: '"jhhjh":"ssss"}',

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){ console.log(data);
    },
    failure: function(errMsg) {
        console.log(errMsg);
    }
});
```

Then on server side I have this code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyParser());

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // set origin policy etc so cross-domain access wont be an issue

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    // that is the line that gives me error message and cannot return anything back to client
    res.send("all good");
});

app.post('/', function(req, res) {


});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3800);
```

However as json I'm trying to pass to server is invalid my Express crashes and I cant do anything about this. I cant catch it or anything. How can I catch this error?

```
Error: invalid json
    at parse (C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:60:15)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\body-parser\index.js:156:18
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\xampp\htdocs\testing\node_modules\body-parser\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:113:7)
    at IncomingMessage.g (events.js:180:16)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at _stream_readable.js:920:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

How can I catch this error? What I need is to detect if json passed is invalid and return `400` with json message `{ "someerror":"somemessage"}`

Comment: Did you try adding an Express error handler? `app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { /* check err */ });`

Comment: yes it did nothing :(

Comment: Where did you add the error handler? I generally add one towards the end of the middleware stack and after routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in the server.js:

```
var express = require("express"),
app = express(),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(function(err,req,res,next){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
}
next();
});

app.all('/', function(req, res, next) {
    // set origin policy etc so cross-domain access wont be an issue

    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With,  Content-Type, Accept");
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
});
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    if(!Object.keys(req.body))
        res.json('all good');
    else
        res.json({
            success: false,
            error: "json invalid"
        }, 400);


});



app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3800);
```

Comment: you sir are a genius! The funny thing is (funny for those watching me for last couple of hours, not so much for me) that I had similar app.use(fu... call but it was never getting triggered. Its working now, I'm just trying to find out where I did wrong. Thank you!!!