# How to make a JSON String Valid, if it's not?

Tags: javascript, json, validation

I have a requirement where I get json string from other API, and this string may or may not be  a valid JSON string. How do I Check if the JSON String is valid or not, if it's not valid, how can I make it valid ? What I mean to ask is if there are certain characters that need to be escaped and if they are not escaped then we get error while parsing. Do we have any API to make a JSON string valid ?

I got the code to check if a JSON string is valid or not

**Javascript**

```
if (/^[\],:{}\s]*$/.test('{section : "ABCDEFGHI"JKLMNOP"}'.replace(/\\["\\\/bfnrtu]/g, '@').
replace(/"[^"\\\n\r]*"|true|false|null|-?\d+(?:\.\d*)?(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?/g, ']').
replace(/(?:^|:|,)(?:\s*\[)+/g, ''))) {
  console.log('valid');
}else{
    console.log('Not a valid');
}
```

Comment: *"Do we have any API to make a json string valid?"* Not built-in. It seems like you already know how to check whether it's valid or not ([since you got the code from here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3710506/218196)). So, is *making* it valid your actual question?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if a string is a valid JSON string in JavaScript without using Try/Catch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try)

Comment: @loanburger Could be possible, but i need a way to make it valid.

Comment: Making it valid is not trivial, since there is not always a unique solution. Take `"foo\c"` for example. It's not valid JSON because `\c` is an invalid escape sequence. But did I mean to write `"fooc"` or `"foo\\c"` or maybe even `"foo\nc"` ? Before you think about how to make JSON valid, you have to come up with some rules. Then you can implement your own parser which can handle that.

Comment: Then change the title of your question to better reflect what you are asking.

Comment: Let's say we have the following JSON: `'foo'`. How would you "make it valid"?

Answer (score 0):

That is a non trivial problem. It all depends on your definition of "valid" json. You can turn any string into valid json by escaping quote characters and treating it as a string. For example,

```
{"foo":"bar
```

can become

```
{"stringified":"{\"foo\":\"bar"}
```

and it is completely valid, but it could also become

```
{"foo":"bar"}
```

or

```
{"foo":"barcelona"}
```

I would suggest taking another look at your domain or providing a specific problem set in the question.