# Is there a way that I can verify if a file is json format(not missing comma or something) in a console?

Tags: json, node.js

That's it, i'm a careless guy, i always miss something or what if i'm writing a json.
I think maybe we can utilize irb.

Comment: Try checking out this answer from another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3710506

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a super simple one, just use node, then require this json file.

Answer (score 2):

Before looking at Node, look at your editor. Does it do plugins (say, Sublime Text)? If so, install a JSON linter/validator that won't let you save until you've fixed the errors. Problem solved.

No such luck? Look into using grunt or gulp with a simple JSON validator task (of the kind "look for **/*.json, check that"). e.g. https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-jsonlint or https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-jsonlint ...

Or, even just use plain old https://www.npmjs.org/package/jsonlint on its own to check individual files.

This is a solved problem, pick your favourite solution.

Answer (score 1):

You could always create an alias:

```
alias jsonlint="echo \"try{JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync(process.argv[2])); process.exit(0);}catch(e){process.exit(1);}\" | node"
```

and use it like:

```
jsonlint some_file.json
```

or if you don't want the error output

```
jsonlint some_file.json 2>/dev/null
```

In spite of what Snowmanzzz said, `require('some_json.json')` isn't guaranteed to detect the file as JSON (especially if it doesn't have the `.json` extension).