# How to check if the response of a fetch is a json object in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I'm using fetch polyfill to retrieve a JSON or text from a URL, I want to know how can I check if the response is a JSON object or is it only text

```
fetch(URL, options).then(response => {
   // how to check if response has a body of type json?
   if (response.isJson()) return response.json();
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20392392/402037

Answer (score 336, accepted):

You could check for the `content-type` of the response, as shown in [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers):

```
fetch(myRequest).then(response => {
  const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
  if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
    return response.json().then(data => {
      // The response was a JSON object
      // Process your data as a JavaScript object
    });
  } else {
    return response.text().then(text => {
      // The response wasn't a JSON object
      // Process your text as a String
    });
  }
});
```

If you need to be absolutely sure that the content is a valid JSON (and don't trust the headers), you could always just accept the response as `text` and parse it yourself:

```
fetch(myRequest)
  .then(response => response.text()) // Parse the response as text
  .then(text => {
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(text); // Try to parse the response as JSON
      // The response was a JSON object
      // Do your JSON handling here
    } catch(err) {
      // The response wasn't a JSON object
      // Do your text handling here
    }
  });
```

**Async/await**

If you're using `async/await`, you could write it in a more linear fashion:

```
async function myFetch(myRequest) {
  try {
    const reponse = await fetch(myRequest);
    const text = await response.text(); // Parse it as text
    const data = JSON.parse(text); // Try to parse it as JSON
    // The response was a JSON object
    // Do your JSON handling here
  } catch(err) {
    // The response wasn't a JSON object
    // Do your text handling here
  }
}
```

Comment: Via the same strategy you could just use response.json in combination with catch; if you catch an error, it means it's not json. Wouldn't that be a more idiomatic way of handling this (instead of ditching response.json)?

Comment: @WouterRonteltap : Aren't you only allowed to do one or the other. It seems like I remember that you only get one shot at response.anything(). If so, JSON is text, but text isn't necessarily JSON. Therefore, you have to do the sure-thing first, which is .text(). If you do .json() first, and it fails, I don't think you'll get the opportunity to also do .text(). If I'm wrong, please show me different.

Comment: In my opinion you can't trust the headers (even though you should, but sometimes you just can't control the server on the other side). So it's great that you also mention try-catch in your answer.

Comment: Yes, @Lonnie Best is completely correct in this. if you call .json() and it throws an exception (because the response isn't json), you will get a "Body has already been consumed" exception if you subsequently call .text()

Comment: having problems with random badly formated Json this is THE solution [ clear & short ]

Comment: @Andy you can call response.clone() to get cloned instance and therefore you can call .json() or .text() multiple times.
Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone

Comment: As the https://stevenklambert.com/writing/fetch-json-text-fallback/ article mentions it too, using clone(), u can just:

fetch('/file')
  .then(response => 
    response.clone().json().catch(() => response.text())
  ).then(data => {
    // data is now parsed JSON or raw text
  });

Answer (score 20):

You can do this cleanly with a helper function:

```js
const parseJson = async response => {
  const text = await response.text()
  try{
    const json = JSON.parse(text)
    return json
  } catch(err) {
    throw new Error("Did not receive JSON, instead received: " + text)
  }
}
```

And then use it like this:

```js
fetch(URL, options)
.then(parseJson)
.then(result => {
    console.log("My json: ", result)
})
```

This will throw an error so you can `catch` it if you want.

Comment: Very nice! It will still create a 404 error in the browser's console if the URL doesn't exist at all, but I guess it's unavoidable.

Answer (score 1):

`Fetch` returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch). with Promise chain, a one liner like this would work.

```js
const res = await fetch(url, opts).then(r => r.clone().json().catch(() => r.text()));
```

[image]

Comment: [`catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) expects a function type parameter and not the return value of `r.text()`

Comment: Thanks @PeterSeliger for pointing out the problem in .catch(r.text()). My eslint has correct mine to .catch(() => r.text()). And I have not looked back and assumed it was working.

Comment: this was a saver

Comment: bad idea .  it can be prevented to show error

Answer (score 0):

Use a JSON parser like JSON.parse:

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        var obj = JSON.parse(str);

         // More strict checking     
         // if (obj && typeof obj === "object") {
         //    return true;
         // }

    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i decided to use this one

```js
   return fetch(url).then(async k =>{
             const res = await k.text();
             if(res.startsWith("[") || res.startsWith("{")){
                return JSON.parse(res);
             }
             console.warn(url + " Did not pass Json Format");   
             return [];
            }).then(g => {          
          ////
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

I recently published an `npm` [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onstage-js-utils) that includes common utility functions.
one of these functions that I implemented there is just like the [nis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37121496/5405415)'s `async/await` answer that you can use as bellow:

```js
import {fetchJsonRes, combineURLs} from "onstage-js-utilities";

fetch(combineURLs(HOST, "users"))
    .then(fetchJsonRes)
    .then(json => {
        // json data
    })
    .catch(err => {
        // when the data is not json
    })
```

you can find the source on [Github](https://github.com/saeidalidadi/js-utilities#interceptors)