# Invalid format of JSON-response?

Tags: c#, json

I'm having issues trying to deserialize the JSON received from an external source. I'm not sure but I think it might be the JSON itself which is wrong, or else I'm doing it all wrong. Could someone shed a light on this?

This is the JSON I'm receiving:

```
{"results": {"result": 32}},{"statistics": {"positive": 47.3,"negative": 49.6,"breakeven": 3.1}}
```

These are my classes:

```
public class dataClass
{
    public resultsClass results { get; set; }
    public statisticsClass statistics { get; set; }
}

public class resultsClass
{
    public int result { get; set; }
}

public class statisticsClass
{
    public Double? positive { get; set; }
    public Double? negative { get; set; }
    public Double? breakeven { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I deserialize:

```
dataClass output = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataClass>(response);
```

When I try to deserialize this, I'm getting the error:

> Additional text encountered after finished reading JSON content

And I've pinned it down to the comma in between the results and the statistics. I think the closing bracket of results and the opening bracket of statistics should not be there.

Or am I deserializing wrong?

Comment: The text *is* wrong. You have two separate dictionaries with a `,` between them. You need to surround the entire string with `{}`

Comment: Try *serializing* an object first, to see how it should look like

Comment: They've concatenated two separate valid bits of JSON with a comma separator. If you can split the response into two parts you could deserialize each bit separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you parse the json into a text editor you can see that in that response you have double root element. the result , and the statistics are separated.

You have to choice :

1. Separate the string json :
   You have to split the two root element and aply the  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dataClass>(response);` for each root element
2. Modify the json response stucture (Recommended):
   the json response is wrong !! , if you are the owner of the response you can modify the response to this : `{
   "results": {
       "result": 32
   },
   "statistics": {
       "positive": 47.3,
       "negative": 49.6,
       "breakeven": 3.1
   }
   }` and should be works with your code.

Regards,

Answer (score 4):

your JSON is formatted incorrectly.
According to [this sites](http://jsonlint.com/#) validation:

```
Error: Parse error on line 5:
...     "result": 32    }}, {   "statistics": {
--------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','
```

This works:

```
{
    "results": {
        "result": 32
    },
    "statistics": {
        "positive": 47.3,
        "negative": 49.6,
        "breakeven": 3.1
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I suspected. However the problem is that this is a JSON provided by a third party from whom I don't have any contact details. Is there an easy way to fix this? Right now I'm thinking of re-formatting the reponse.

Comment: Yes.  Reformat or let them know that they are sending you junk.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try) is a link on how to verify