# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data app.js:31:24

Tags: jquery, json

I just set up a jquery post that parses the result.  I keep `JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data app.js:31:24`

Not sure why this isn't working.  I currently have the `/api/word` endpoint returning the result if it exists on the post, if not it returns a queue id that is then polled to the same endpoint with a `GET` that returns false until the result is available.

here is my `app.js`

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    var configOptions = {
        endpoint : '/api/word'
    };

    jQuery(document).ready(run);

    function run() {
        jQuery('form').on('submit', submitForm);
    }

    function submitForm(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var data = jQuery(e.currentTarget).serialize();

        jQuery('button').prop('disabled', true);

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: configOptions.endpoint,
            method: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: readQueueResults,
            error: showError
        });

        function readQueueResults(response) {
            console.log(response);
            var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);

            var interval = setInterval(function () {
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: configOptions.endpoint,
                    method: 'GET',
                    data: 'id=' + data.id,
                    success: showResults
                });
            }, 500);

            function showResults(response) {
                if (response) {
                    clearInterval(interval);

                    jQuery('button').prop('disabled', false);

                    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
                    renderMessage('alert-success', 'Your word is <b>' + data.percent + '%</b> pronounceable');
                }
            }
        }

        function showError(error) {
            console.warn(error.status, error.statusText);

            jQuery('button').prop('disabled', false);

            renderMessage('alert-danger', '<b>' + error.status + '</b> - ' + error.statusText);
        }
    }

    function renderMessage(classes, message) {
        jQuery('.alert').remove();

        var div = jQuery('<div>', {class: 'alert clear text-center row ' + classes});
        div.append(message);
        div.appendTo('.col-md-6');
    }

}());
```

the console log is either

`18828f7e-5554-43ee-8d3c-b00abe1409ca`

or

`Object {pronounceability: "0.0"}`

Comment: please post the json response you're getting from console log

Comment: @KAD just added the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm using `Flask` it sends back a parsed object already so I had to take out `jQuery.parseJSON(response)` to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Most likely JSON is malformed. Remember, that JSON notation is only a subset of JavaScript object syntax. For example, if you forget to put keys inside of double quotes, parser will reject such object. Please post the JSON that you try to parse.

You can also check if your JSON is valid with one of many online JSON validation tools like this one: http://jsonlint.com/

EDIT (after console.log is posted): it looks like the problem is on the serverside, neither of two console outputs is a valid JSON string.

Comment: I just posted the json response

Answer (score 0):

From the log it seems both returned types are not well formed JSON, the result shall be a string in well formed JSON for the `jQuery.parseJSON` to properly parse it.

Making a checking is beneficial as follows:

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710226/2611451