# How to alter behavior of JSON.parse()?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to alter the behavior of JSON.parse is there anyway to do this in JS?

I need to do this because we are encountering some errors when trying to parse as json some data that the backend is returning as html.

Comment: Override its prototype

Comment: Shouldn't you rather be fixing the backend so that it sends valid JSON?

Comment: If you cant fix the back end, maybe pre-process the data before parsing?

Comment: What have you tried? It sounds like you want others to write error handling code for you

Comment: @NickSlash i'd try that the problem is that the JSON.parse() is being called from an angularjs native piece of code which I have no control over. So that is why I wanted to change the JSON.parse()

Comment: Use an angular `httpIinterceptor`. Why is html being sent with incorrect content type header though? Or perhaps json is not sent with proper header?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can by overriding the method:

```js
JSON.parse = function(str) {
  console.log(str);
}
JSON.parse([1, 2]);
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use try-catch to handle the response recieved from the backend as described here

[How to check if a string is a valid JSON string in JavaScript without using Try/Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try/3710226)

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```