# Try/Catch Functions: False versus Falsy

Tags: javascript, optimization, micro-optimization, ecmascript-next

This is a petty question that will make you cringe, but I'm still curious.

Is it slightly more efficient (for if/then logic) to evaluate an explicit `false` over [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values such a `null` or `undefined`?

When I `try/catch` inside of a function, with the intent of recovering from an unimportant (yet) application-halting error, I typically returned `undefined` when the try portion cannot not succeed.

However, below I'm returning `false` instead of `undefined`:

```js
var parseJSON = function(jsonString)
{
 try
 {
  var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
  if (obj && typeof obj === "object")
  {
   return obj;
  }
 }
 catch (error)
 {
  console.log(` JSON error, but no need to halt.`);
 }
 return false; //false will not require coercion later, right?
};

let testInput = `This is NOT JSON!`;


if (parseJSON(testInput))
{
 console.log("Success, JSON was parsed");
}
else
{
 console.log("Is it faster to get here from an explicit false than a falsy value?")
}
```

I totally realize that the differences are negligible. Yet, you do have to choose, so why not choose the fastest choice if there is one. Instead of just concluding it doesn't matter, I'd like to give this topic a moment of consideration once and for all.

Comment: By writing this, you've used more time than you will ever possibly save with that optimization... anyway, I would vote for `x === null` if that's possible, if not, then `x === undefined`

Comment: Note boolean values (primitives in general) can be parsed/stringified from/to json `JSON.stringify(false)` and `JSON.parse("false")` so technically `parseJSON()` shouldnt return `false` as that could have been a valid JSON that was being parsed.

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Do whatever you feel is most natural and readable, and optimize it if it becomes a performance bottleneck.

Comment: FYI, It is a convention to use `null` to explicitly set a non value, instead of `undefined`, to let developers know the value was intentionally set to that, instead of being undefined which could mean the value was never set, indicating an issue with data flow.

Comment: "*Yet, you do have to choose, so why not choose the fastest choice if there is one*" because I may want to choose the more clear choice? `false` doesn't (necessarily) mean that you've failed to parse JSON, while a more explicit `undefined` is. Although if you do get `"false"` (valid JSON) or `"42"` (also valid JSON) your function would actually return `undefined` instead of the correct values `false` or `42`.

Comment: This is exactly why `JSON.parse()` throws instead of just returning `null`, `false` etc for a failed parse.

Comment: Also, do note than any potential speed increase you theoretically get from using `false` instead of `undefined`, is offset many times over by the `try/catch` which will be way slower than any amount of `if` checks. Yet, the speed still won't matter unless you are doing exceptionally performance critical stuff...in which case you'd be somewhat unlikely to do them in JS.

Comment: To me it's much more semantic to return *undefined* in this case. Presumably you're using *try..catch* to avoid an error from invalid JSON, in that case it's misleading to return *false* or even *null*. The *undefined* value says it all: the result of the parse is undefined (because it threw an error). The performance issue is irrelevant as you're trying to second guess what the caller will do with the result.

Comment: I like fatures, my parseJSON would have an additional param, for the default return value, it would also check the typeof the value passed, if throws return default value. You making a function which confines you, your end up doing it manually again in your code as your eventually hate working with parseJSON as it borks if you dont pass it correct json or use it where your type checking the value.

Comment: @Barmar: That doesn't make it off-topic to ask about the details of what happens in existing JS engines like V8.  It would be a better question if it asked about any specific JIT engines explicitly, though.  And probably if it wasn't about converting try/catch to a return value/error code but instead something simple like `if (x < 0) return false` or something for a pretend sqrt function. Anyway, it sounds reasonable to ask if there's any significant difference in how return false vs. undefined JIT into asm for a real ISA like x86-64. Other considerations might outweigh for real use, of course

Comment: @PeterCordes I never said this was off-topic, I just suggested that the OP is probably wasting their time worrying about it.

Comment: @Barmar: that's fair.  I think there's an interesting question here for people idly curious about how JS engines work and perform.  I agree the answer is probably not relevant to actually writing JS code, though; semantic meaning considerations probably outweight any difference unless there surprisingly turns out to be a huge perf different on any JS engine, and even then only in rare cases where you still need error checking inside the hottest part of some perf-critical code.