# unable to access properties of objects inside array of JSON objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

```js
{
  "results_found": "53",
  "results_start": "11",
  "results_shown": "10",
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "id": "16774318",
      "name": "Otto Enoteca & Pizzeria",
      "url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village",
      "location": {
        "address": "1 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10003",
        "locality": "Greenwich Village",
        "city": "New York City",
        "latitude": "40.732013",
        "longitude": "-73.996155",
        "zipcode": "10003",
        "country_id": "216"
      },
      "average_cost_for_two": "60",
      "price_range": "2",
      "currency": "$",
      "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/8/16774318/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_thumb.png",
      "featured_image": "https://d.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/8/16774318/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_v2.png",
      "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/photos#tabtop",
      "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/menu#tabtop",
      "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/events#tabtop",
      "user_rating": {
        "aggregate_rating": "3.7",
        "rating_text": "Very Good",
        "rating_color": "5BA829",
        "votes": "1046"
      },
      "has_online_delivery": "0",
      "is_delivering_now": "0",
      "has_table_booking": "0",
      "deeplink": "zomato://r/16774318",
      "cuisines": "Cafe",
      "all_reviews_count": "15",
      "photo_count": "18",
      "phone_numbers": "(212) 228-2930"
      
    }
  ]
}
```

Not able to access property "**name**" in "**restaurants**" array in node js.When I am parsing the body using JSON like,
          var data = JSON.parse(body);

and trying to print "**data**"...the result is:

```
{
  "results_found": 0,
  "results_start": 0,
  "results_shown": 0,
  "restaurants": []
}
```

What may be the reason?? I am confused...the JSON is from Zomato API.

Comment: Seems the `body` JSON is not what you expect it to be

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is a valid JSON string in JavaScript without using Try/Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try)

Comment: No mine is a different issue...@Codebreaker007

Answer (score 1):

JSON value you have posted is not valid format.. you have a trailing coma after ']'
please use this a valid JSON file

```
{
  "results_found": "53",
  "results_start": "11",
  "results_shown": "10",
  "restaurants": [
    {
      "id": "16774318",
      "name": "Otto Enoteca & Pizzeria",
      "url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village",
      "location": {
        "address": "1 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10003",
        "locality": "Greenwich Village",
        "city": "New York City",
        "latitude": "40.732013",
        "longitude": "-73.996155",
        "zipcode": "10003",
        "country_id": "216"
      },
      "average_cost_for_two": "60",
      "price_range": "2",
      "currency": "$",
      "thumb": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/8/16774318/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_thumb.png",
      "featured_image": "https://d.zmtcdn.com/data/pictures/chains/8/16774318/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_v2.png",
      "photos_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/photos#tabtop",
      "menu_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/menu#tabtop",
      "events_url": "https://www.zomato.com/new-york-city/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village/events#tabtop",
      "user_rating": {
        "aggregate_rating": "3.7",
        "rating_text": "Very Good",
        "rating_color": "5BA829",
        "votes": "1046"
      },
      "has_online_delivery": "0",
      "is_delivering_now": "0",
      "has_table_booking": "0",
      "deeplink": "zomato://r/16774318",
      "cuisines": "Cafe",
      "all_reviews_count": "15",
      "photo_count": "18",
      "phone_numbers": "(212) 228-2930",
      "photos": [
        {
          "id": "u_MjA5MjY1OTk5OT",
          "url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/reviews_photos/c15/9eb13ceaf6e90129c276ce6ff980bc15_1435111695_640_640_thumb.JPG",
          "thumb_url": "https://b.zmtcdn.com/data/reviews_photos/c15/9eb13ceaf6e90129c276ce6ff980bc15_1435111695_200_thumb.JPG",
          "user": {
            "name": "John Doe",
            "zomato_handle": "John",
            "foodie_level": "Super Foodie",
            "foodie_level_num": "9",
            "foodie_color": "f58552",
            "profile_url": "https://www.zomato.com/john",
            "profile_deeplink": "zoma.to/u/1170245",
            "profile_image": "string"
          },
          "res_id": "16782899",
          "caption": "#awesome",
          "timestamp": "1435111770",
          "friendly_time": "3 months ago",
          "width": "640",
          "height": "640",
          "comments_count": "0",
          "likes_count": "0"
        }
      ]

    }
  ]
}
```

Sample snippet with above JSON

```js
var json = "{\"results_found\":\"53\",\"results_start\":\"11\",\"results_shown\":\"10\",\"restaurants\":[{\"id\":\"16774318\",\"name\":\"Otto Enoteca & Pizzeria\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/new-york-city\/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village\",\"location\":{\"address\":\"1 5th Avenue, New York, NY 10003\",\"locality\":\"Greenwich Village\",\"city\":\"New York City\",\"latitude\":\"40.732013\",\"longitude\":\"-73.996155\",\"zipcode\":\"10003\",\"country_id\":\"216\"},\"average_cost_for_two\":\"60\",\"price_range\":\"2\",\"currency\":\"$\",\"thumb\":\"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/pictures\/chains\/8\/16774318\/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_thumb.png\",\"featured_image\":\"https:\/\/d.zmtcdn.com\/data\/pictures\/chains\/8\/16774318\/a54deb9e4dbb79dd7c8091b30c642077_featured_v2.png\",\"photos_url\":\"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/new-york-city\/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village\/photos#tabtop\",\"menu_url\":\"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/new-york-city\/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village\/menu#tabtop\",\"events_url\":\"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/new-york-city\/otto-enoteca-pizzeria-greenwich-village\/events#tabtop\",\"user_rating\":{\"aggregate_rating\":\"3.7\",\"rating_text\":\"Very Good\",\"rating_color\":\"5BA829\",\"votes\":\"1046\"},\"has_online_delivery\":\"0\",\"is_delivering_now\":\"0\",\"has_table_booking\":\"0\",\"deeplink\":\"zomato:\/\/r\/16774318\",\"cuisines\":\"Cafe\",\"all_reviews_count\":\"15\",\"photo_count\":\"18\",\"phone_numbers\":\"(212) 228-2930\",\"photos\":[{\"id\":\"u_MjA5MjY1OTk5OT\",\"url\":\"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/reviews_photos\/c15\/9eb13ceaf6e90129c276ce6ff980bc15_1435111695_640_640_thumb.JPG\",\"thumb_url\":\"https:\/\/b.zmtcdn.com\/data\/reviews_photos\/c15\/9eb13ceaf6e90129c276ce6ff980bc15_1435111695_200_thumb.JPG\",\"user\":{\"name\":\"John Doe\",\"zomato_handle\":\"John\",\"foodie_level\":\"Super Foodie\",\"foodie_level_num\":\"9\",\"foodie_color\":\"f58552\",\"profile_url\":\"https:\/\/www.zomato.com\/john\",\"profile_deeplink\":\"zoma.to\/u\/1170245\",\"profile_image\":\"string\"},\"res_id\":\"16782899\",\"caption\":\"#awesome\",\"timestamp\":\"1435111770\",\"friendly_time\":\"3 months ago\",\"width\":\"640\",\"height\":\"640\",\"comments_count\":\"0\",\"likes_count\":\"0\"}]}]}"

var data = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: The extra comma happenned while copy pasting the code from Zomato API.The error is happening for other reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Your json is not valid. There is an extra comma at the end of `restaurants[0].photos` please remove it and everything will work fine

Comment: The extra comma happenned while copy pasting the code from Zomato API.The error is happening for other reasons.