# Type of this is always object while checking for a valid Javascrip Object

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I wrote a Prototype function in javascript to determine whether an entity is a valid Javascript object or not. Something like following

```
// Check if Object is Valid & Have at least one element

Object.prototype._isValidObject = function () {
    return this && typeof this === 'object' && !Array.isArray(this) && Object.keys(this).length >= 1;
};
```

The problem is it is returning **TRUE** for most of the values, like even for **string**, cause **this** is treated like an object for any value, like arrays, strings or json etc. There may be other ways to do this, but I need to make a prototype function for this. Please determine the correct way to Determine whether a value is a valid Javascript object having atleast one item. Thanks

**EDIT**
By Valid Javascript / JSON Object I mean something like this:

```
{
  id:100,
  name:'somename',
  email:'maiL@mail.com'
}
```

To be more precise following is what I want:

```
const j = {id:100,name:'somename', email:'maiL@mail.com'};

const s = "{id:100, name:'somename', email:'maiL@mail.com'}"; 

j._isValidObject(); // Should return true
s._isValidObject(); // Should return false
```

const j is valid for me cause it is an object having key-value pairs. const s is invalid for me cause it's a string representation of an object, not the object itself. const s can be converted to valid Object like const j, but right now const s is just a string.

**EDIT**
I have found a solution, and posted it in answers. Though I am not marking it as accepted answer since I'm not sure whether it's the best way to do it. If somebody has a better solution, please post it. Thanks

Comment: Please define what exactly "a valid JSON object" is first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check if a string is a valid JSON string in JavaScript without using Try/Catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try)

Comment: Note: Check second answer, not the accepted.

Comment: By definition, any Javascript object is a valid object, and since almost anything is an object, pretty much everything is. It might be easier to ask what exactly you want to *exclude*.

Comment: @Wimanicesir that's for checking whether a string is a valid JSON or not. In my question the value can be a JSON already, I need to confirm it just. If it's a string, whether it's a json string, it should return false, if it's already a JSON object, it should return true. I don't want to confirm whether a string is in JSON format or not

Comment: Because your prototype is on `Object`, everything is being *cast* to an `Object`. I modified your function like so: `Object.prototype._isValidObject = function () {
    return typeof this;
};`, then I ran `"hello word"._isValidObject()` - this outputs `Object`, so you can't use this method with `typeof`

Comment: @Luke yes, you are right. So what's the getaway with this.

Comment: What about `JSON.parse('"Foo"')`. The result is `"Foo"`, a Javascript string, but not JSON…

Comment: Now that we have come to an understanding about what a JavaScript object is, you still need to define what constitutes a "valid" JavaScript object. Is a date object valid? Is a DOM element object valid?

Comment: [Turning this around,](http://xyproblem.info) what problem is it you're trying to solve? You don't know whether any one particular variable holds a JSON string that must be decoded or an already decoded value? As illustrated above with my string example, that's a bad situation to find yourself in, since the question isn't really answerable for strings in general. This is a problem that would need to be solved with a better definition of your data flow; i.e. you *should know* at any one point whether you expect to have JSON or a Javascript value. You shouldn't need to guess at all.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen, please check the example i have given in the end of my EDIT section. I just want that. const j is valid for me cause it is an object having key-value pairs. const s is invalid for me cause it's a string representation of an object, not the object itself. const s can be converted to valid Object like const j, but right now const s is just a string.

Comment: What you are likely looking for is whether it is a POJO (plain old javascript object),
See https://github.com/jonschlinkert/is-plain-object and the [source](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/is-plain-object/blob/master/index.js). Read the usage to see exactly which cases it supports and which not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, though I am not marking as accepted answer since I'm not sure whether it's the best way to do it. If somebody has a better solution, please post it. Thanks

```
// Check if Object is Valid & Have at least one element

Object.prototype._isValidObject = function () {
    return this
           && !(this instanceof String)
           && !Array.isArray(this)
           && Object.keys(this).length >= 1;
};
```

Comment: `console.log(console._isValidObject());` Nobody but you can answer your question because you have still not shared your definition of what constitutes a valid object.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned in my example in edit section that for me a valid object is one which has a key-value relation, like a hash-map, whose values can be accesses by accessing the key-name as an index. Like we access a class member in any oops programming language by creating the object of the class. It shouldn't be the string representation, but an actual object

Comment: The problem, *any* Javascript object fits that definition (except for special values like `undefined`).

Comment: That i realized. That's why i am asking for a solution to differentiate between string representation and bytecode object. var obj = new C1(); var str  = "class C1{}";. We can't say str is an object of class C1. It's just a string representation. obj is an object. So there is a difference between var s = {} and var j = "{}".

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, so the only clear rule appears to be: "is it a string?" But again, if it is a string, that doesn't automatically mean it's a JSON string either, it could very well just be a… string. To give a *useful* solution to your question, we'd need to know to what extent you have considered this and how relevant that concern is.