# Convert nested Json string to object and render in Jquery datatable cell

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I want to convert Json string into object and render it's specific value in JQuery Datatable Cell. I tried several hours for this but didn't able to achieve.

**Json Example**

```
[
{ "id":1, "Error": "Name missing in datatable"},
{ "id":2, "Error": "{\"ErrorType\": \"401\", \"InnerException\":\"Invalid request, Please correct and submit\"}" }
]
```

First I want to check if *Error* is normal string or json string, if normal string show as it is and if json string convert it into json object and render *InnerException* into datatable cell. i tried following code but didn't get correct result.

**My code Example**

```
var RespTable = $('#dtResponse').DataTable({
data: dataList,
columns: [
{ "title": "ID", "data": "id", "defaultContent": ""},
{ 
"title": "Error Message",
"data": "Error",
"defaultContent": "",
"render": function (data, type) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(data)
  if (obj != undefined)
  return obj.InnerException;
  else
  return data
  }
}
]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are close. If you can rely on the text containing "InnerException" (if there is an inner exception, of course), then you can do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

let dataList = [{
        "id": 1,
        "Error": "Name missing in datatable"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "Error": "{\"ErrorType\": \"401\", \"InnerException\":\"Invalid request, Please correct and submit\"}"
    }
];

  $(document).ready(function() {

    let RespTable = $('#dtResponse').DataTable( {
      data: dataList,
      columns: [
        { "title": "ID", "data": "id", "defaultContent": ""},
        { "title": "Error Message", "data": "Error", "defaultContent": "",
          "render": function (data, type) {
            if ( data.includes("InnerException") ) {
              let innerJson = JSON.parse(data);
              //console.log(innerJson);
              return innerJson.InnerException;
            } else {
              return data;
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    
  } );

} );

</script>
```

This uses `data.includes("InnerException")` as the test to see if it is OK to parse the string as JSON, or not.

The end result:

[image]

**Update**

A more rigorous approach is to add a function such as this:

```
function IsJsonString(str) {
    try {
        JSON.parse(str);
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then we can replace our string test with this:

```
if ( IsJsonString(data) ) {...}
```

Comment: What if Error string contains InnerException as a word? like "Error": "Name missing in datatable, see InnerException  for more detail"

Comment: If there is no safe string test, then yes - this is not a suitable approach.

Comment: I have added a function you can use as a JSON tester.

Comment: If those options are not suitable (string check and try/catch), I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try) has some more approaches you can investigate.

Comment: I don't know using function like this is efficient way or it will work in all scenarios but its working for me.

Comment: Yes - I am sure you are correct - this is not the most efficient approach (relying on a try/catch like this - and potentially performing the operation twice). I imagine it could be improved.