# Javascript how to check if incoming param is an object

Tags: javascript, json, lwc

How to check if an incoming param to my function is an proper object in javascript?

code

```
function abc(object1, data1) {
    if(i need to verify here object1 is a proper JSON then only it should proceed) {
        //do the operation
    }
}
```

Comment: object1 is JSON string or JavaScript object ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a value is an object in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8511281/check-if-a-value-is-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: it must be a JSON

Comment: Again, JSON string and JavaScript object is different thing. Please be more specific so we can help you.

Comment: Then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try should answer your question. (note: the question was about doing it without using `try/catch`)

Comment: sorry that dosen't help i need to put a check in if condition if the incoming parameter is JSON

Comment: kindly help me out for this one...

Comment: What are you passing? You call it object1 but is it `'{"a":"b","c":"d"}'` or `{"a":"b","c":"d"}`

Answer (score 2):

The function below can be used to check if provided data is a valid JSON, for an object (`string`, `boolean`, ...) it will return `false`:

```
const isJson = (data) => {
   try {
      return Boolean(JSON.parse(data));
   } catch {
      return false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function abc(object1, data1) {
    let isJson;
    try {
        JSON.parse(object1);
        isJson = true;
    } catch (ignore) {}
    if (isJson) {
        //do the operation
        console.log("object1 - " + object1 + " - is json-parseable");
        return;
    }
    console.log("object1 - " + object1 + " - is not json-parseable");
}

// test
abc("null");            // object1 - null - is json-parseable
abc("{\"aa\":\"bb\"}"); // object1 - {"aa":"bb"} - is json-parseable
abc(undefined);         // object1 - undefined - is not json-parseable
abc("syntax error");    // object1 - syntax error - is not json-parseable
```