# Checking a key is array or string in JSONObject

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a JSONObject

```
{"notes":{
"remarks":["abc","xyz"],
"factory notes":["abc","xyz"],
"name":"jdfb"
}
}
```

**
i want to insert it to a table as remarks as a string factory notes as a string and name is already a string. but when i iterate this how do i know if it is array or string. whats the condition for that?

for name i could do obj.getString("name"), and for array its getJsonarray. if i can distinguish that i could easily convert it to string and inset to the table.**

```
String description=null;
                 Iterator<String> notesIterator = notesObj.keys();

                 while (notesIterator.hasNext()) {
                     String notesKey = notesIterator.next();
                     Object notesItrObj=notesIterator.next();
                 
                   
                     if(notesItrObj instanceof String ) {
                         description=notesObj.getString(notesKey);

                     }
                     else {

                      
                         JSONArray
notesArray=notesObj.getJSONArray(notesKey);
                       
                         description=notesArray.toString();
              

      


                 }
```

Comment: You can use `Array.isArray(your_variable)`

Comment: no that wont work

Comment: how come? I used `Array.isArray(a["notes"]["factory notes"])` and it return true, `Array.isArray(a["notes"]["name"])` return false which mean it's string

Comment: have you considered the fact its a jsonObject?

Comment: i have  a jsonObject when i iterate it i get the key remarks . because i also need the key to insert to table. all i want is to check if the value of key is an array or not

Comment: You mean inside `notes` there maybe string, array or json?

Comment: no notes is json

Comment: Then you could try stringify then regex to check if it's valid json or not https://stackoverflow.com/a/3710506/10400870

Comment: no..no.. that is not my question. the json is valid. i want to stringify it only if it is an array. so how do i check if its an array?

Comment: I already told you, if you need to check if it's array or not, use `Array.isArray(your_variable)`

Comment: And i alreadty told you that wont work for a json obect key

Comment: @DoanVanThang This question appears to be about Java, not JavaScript.

Comment: im afraid no...

Comment: Why not? Please clarify your problem and explain why that solution doesn't work. Otherwise, it's hard for us to help you.

Comment: ok..I am iterating the jsonObject and i get all 3 keys. say the first key is remarks. which is an array. so i ve to stringify that.if it is name i dont need to stringify it. so my quesion is how do check that? i dont know how to explain any more than this

Comment: You mean you want to check the key instead of the value? That wasn't clear from the question. Can you share your code so far?

Comment: no. i want to check the value of the key . ive added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in your code is here:

```
Object notesItrObj=notesIterator.next();
```

This should be:

```
Object notesItrObj=notesObj.get(notesKey);
```

This is because `notesIterator.next()` returns a key, not a value.