# Error parsing JSON: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: d]

Tags: javascript, react-native, openai-api

I have a React Native application where I'm fetching the OpenAI API key from my Node.js backend. Subsequently, I'm using this key to make a request to the OpenAI API for generating AI responses.

The OpenAI API key is successfully retrieved from the backend, but I encounter the following error:

```
ERROR  Error parsing JSON: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: d]
ERROR  Error parsing JSON: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: D]
```

This error seems related to parsing JSON, but I'm having trouble identifying the root cause. Here's the relevant part of my code

```
import { OPENAI_API_KEY_ENDPOINT, OPENAI_API_URL } from "./environment";

export const generateAIDialog = async (userInput) => {
    try {

        const openaiApiKeyResponse = await fetch(OPENAI_API_KEY_ENDPOINT);
        const openaiApiKeyResult = await openaiApiKeyResponse.json();
        const openaiApiKey = openaiApiKeyResult.openaiApiKey;

        // Make request to OpenAI API
        const response = await fetch(OPENAI_API_URL, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${openaiApiKey}`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
                messages: [{ role: 'user', content: userInput }],
                max_tokens: 2000,
                stream: true,
            }),
        });

        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }

        const responseBody = await response.text();

        // Split the response into chunks based on the 'data:' separator
        const chunks = responseBody.split('\ndata: ');

        let aiResponse = '';

        chunks.forEach(chunk => {
            if (chunk.trim() !== '') {
                try {
                    const parsedChunk = JSON.parse(chunk.trim());

                    if (parsedChunk.choices && parsedChunk.choices.length > 0) {
                        const { delta } = parsedChunk.choices[0];
                        const { content } = delta;

                        if (content) {
                            aiResponse += content + ' ';
                        }
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
                }
            }
        });

        return aiResponse.trim();  
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error generating AI response:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

To be specific here:

```
 chunks.forEach(chunk => {
            if (chunk.trim() !== '') {
                try {
                    const parsedChunk = JSON.parse(chunk.trim());

                    if (parsedChunk.choices && parsedChunk.choices.length > 0) {
                        const { delta } = parsedChunk.choices[0];
                        const { content } = delta;

                        if (content) {
                            aiResponse += content + ' ';
                        }
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
                }
            }
        });
```

I suspect the issue might be related to how I'm handling the chunks of the response. Can someone provide guidance on how to correctly parse the JSON response from the OpenAI API in this context?

Additionally, I've included snippets of the React Native code where I fetch the OpenAI API key and make the AI request for better context. Please let me know if there's anything else needed to diagnose the problem.

environment.js

```
export const API_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:3001";

export const DATA_API_ENDPOINT = `${API_BASE_URL}/api/data`;

export const OPENAI_API_KEY_ENDPOINT = `${API_BASE_URL}/api/openai-api-key`;

export const OPENAI_API_URL = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
```

Support.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, View, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Text, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, Platform, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { supportStyles } from '../components/styles/globalStyles';
import { getOpenaiApiKey } from '../Servicefiles/keychecker';
import { generateAIDialog } from '../Servicefiles/OpenAIService';

const Message = ({ text, isUser }) => {
    return (
        <View style={isUser ? supportStyles.userMessage : supportStyles.aiMessage}>
            <Text style={supportStyles.messageText}>{text}</Text>
        </View>
    );
};

const CustomerSupport = () => {
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState('');
    const [chatHistory, setChatHistory] = useState([]);
    const [openaiApiKey, setOpenaiApiKey] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchOpenaiApiKey = async () => {
            try {
                const apiKey = await getOpenaiApiKey();
                setOpenaiApiKey(apiKey);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error fetching OpenAI API key:', error);
            }
        };

        fetchOpenaiApiKey();
    }, []);

    const handleSend = async () => {
      if (inputText.trim() !== '') {
          try {
              const aiResponse = await generateAIDialog(inputText, openaiApiKey);
              setChatHistory(prevHistory => [
                  ...prevHistory,
                  { text: inputText, isUser: true },
                  { text: aiResponse, isUser: false },
              ]);
              setInputText('');
              Keyboard.dismiss();
          } catch (error) {
              console.error('Error sending message to AI:', error);
          }
      }
  };


  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={supportStyles.safecontainer2}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={supportStyles.chatContainer}
        ref={(ref) => {
          // Scroll to the end of the ScrollView when a new message is added
          ref?.scrollToEnd({ animated: true });
        }}
      >
        {chatHistory.map((message, index) => (
          <Message key={index} text={message.text} isUser={message.isUser} />
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <KeyboardAvoidingView 
        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
        style={supportStyles.inputContainer}
        keyboardVerticalOffset={20}
      >
        <View style={supportStyles.textcont}>
          <TextInput
            style={supportStyles.inputField}
            placeholder="Type your problem..."
            value={inputText}
            onChangeText={(text) => setInputText(text)}
            multiline
          />
        </View>
        <TouchableOpacity style={supportStyles.sendButton} onPress={handleSend}>
          <Text style={supportStyles.sendButtonText}>Send</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default CustomerSupport;
```

Keychecker.js

```
import { OPENAI_API_KEY_ENDPOINT } from "./environment";

export const getOpenaiApiKey = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(OPENAI_API_KEY_ENDPOINT);
        
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
        }
        
        const result = await response.json();
        
        return result.openaiApiKey;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching OpenAI API key:', error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

backend

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();
const app = express();
const port = 3001;
const dbPath = './availablecars.db';

app.use(cors());

// Create or connect to the SQLite database
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbPath, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(`Error connecting to the database: ${err.message}`);
    } else {
      console.log(`Connected to the database: ${dbPath}`);
    }
});

// Endpoint for fetching OpenAI API key
app.get('/api/openai-api-key', (req, res) => {
    console.log('Request to /openai-api-key');
    const openaiApiKey = 'api key';
    res.json({ openaiApiKey });
});

//existing endpoint for fetching data
app.get('/api/data', (req, res) => {
    // Fetch data from the database and send it as a response
    const selectQuery = 'SELECT * FROM engine_data';
    db.all(selectQuery, [], (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
            return;
        }
        res.json({ type: 'Engine', data: rows });
    });
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

console log the responsebody content

```
 LOG  response data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"role":"assistant","content":""},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":"Hello"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":"!"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":" How"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":" can"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":" I"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":" assist"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":" you"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":" today"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{"content":"?"},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":null}]}

data: {"id":"chatcmpl-8xGgUuK2uA09gXhQSMx5HS375vbCV","object":"chat.completion.chunk","created":1709136178,"model":"gpt-3.5-turbo-0125","system_fingerprint":"fp_86156a94a0","choices":[{"index":0,"delta":{},"logprobs":null,"finish_reason":"stop"}]}

data: [DONE]
 ERROR  Error parsing JSON: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: d]
 ERROR  Error parsing JSON: [SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected character: D]
```

I Apologize if have put too much thing on here I just wanted to make sure you have all the information you need on the app.
Any guidance or insights into resolving this issue would be highly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Every item in the `JSON.parse(chunk.trim())` is a valid JSON object? Try to evaluate the value using `console.log()` or give us the `responseBody` content

Comment: @Zero i just added the responseBody content

Comment: Seems like `[DONE]` isn't valid; it's an array, but the variable within is undefined. So before you parse, you may need to check for this.

Comment: As @mykaf said, you can just increment the `if` with `if (chunk.trim() !== '' && chunk.trim() !== '[DONE]') {` or create a function to test the JSON and then, prevent that error for unforeseen scenarios, please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string

Comment: Hey I just tried the changes you suggested and the problem has been fixed thank you so 
much @mykaf

Answer (score 0):

The primary change made was the addition of a new function called isValidJson. This function checks if a given string is a valid JSON or not.

```
const isValidJson = (text) => {
    try {
        JSON.parse(text);
        return true;
    } catch (error) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

Then, in the generateAIDialog function, the condition in the forEach loop was updated to check both if the chunk is not empty and if it's a valid JSON before attempting to parse it

```
chunks.forEach(chunk => {
    if (chunk.trim() !== '' && isValidJson(chunk.trim())) {
        try {
            const parsedChunk = JSON.parse(chunk.trim());

            if (parsedChunk.choices && parsedChunk.choices.length > 0) {
                const { delta } = parsedChunk.choices[0];
                const { content } = delta;

                if (content) {
                    aiResponse += content + ' ';
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error parsing JSON:', error);
        }
    }
});
```

This change ensures that the code attempts to parse only valid JSON chunks and avoids parsing chunks like [DONE] that may cause JSON parsing errors