# how to test a json file with json schema file

Tags: javascript, json, jsonschema

I'm newbie to json. I'm learning more things in Json schema but I stood helpless in testing  my **user.json** file against json-schema.json file. Please note I need to test with a javascript variable which should return either true or false to process further. Hereby I  pasted my files.

**json-schema.json**

```
{
  "description": "Any validation failures are shown in the right-hand Messages pane.",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "foo": {
      "type": "number"
    },
    "bar": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**user.json**

```
{
 "foo": 12345,
 "bar": "a"
}
```

When I tested the above code in http://jsonschemalint.com/#/version/draft-05/markup/json   IT say's **user.json** is in right format. But I need to test locally

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test if a string is JSON or not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804777/how-to-test-if-a-string-is-json-or-not)

Comment: In browser or in an app?

Comment: In Browser @Legends

Comment: Hi mahi . I'm well aware about How to test if a string is JSON or not.

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of [JSON schema validators](http://json-schema.org/implementations#validator-javascript).

Example of using one of these libraries, [ajv](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv):

```
import Ajv from 'ajv';

import schema from 'schema.json';
import data from 'data.json';

function isValid(schema, data) {
  const ajv = new Ajv();
  const valid = ajv.validate(schema, data);

  if (!valid) {
    console.log(ajv.errors);
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```