# How to validate a string is JSON or not in Java?

Tags: java, json, methods

I've already said, my question is different...question is already asked   [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java), but i want a predefined method in java which checksgiven string is json format or not.

if there is no predefined method then at least tell a code which checks JSON Format or not, without  using try catch block..

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What's wrong with `try-catch`?

Comment: It can easily be done using `try-catch` as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10174938/2815219).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check whether a given string is valid JSON in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174898/how-to-check-whether-a-given-string-is-valid-json-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

Use **JSONObject's** constructor from a String

```
    try {
        JSONObject o = new JSONObject(yourString);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        LOGGER.error("No valid json");
    }
```

Comment: is there any method ? which doesnt use try catch block?

Comment: AFAIK this is the better way, you can build a method containing that block to avoid writing several catch's. Would that be acceptable according to your requirements?

Comment: thanks for the reply. i just dont wanna use try catch blocks at all. like in javascript we hava a predefined function which validates string is json or not.. so i thought is there anything in java which automatically checks valid json or not.. i want boolean jsIsValid=method(string);

Comment: @edsheeran First of all, Java is not JavaScript. Deal with it. And even [in JavaScript you are supposed to use `try-catch`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9804835/1426227).

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isValidJson(String jsonStr) {
    Object json = new JSONTokener(jsonStr)).nextValue();
    if (json instanceof JSONObject || json instanceof JSONArray) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Just pass any string in this function.

Comment: var jsonStr doesn't appear in function body

Comment: Just fixed the variable naming. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: I think this one need some improvement.

below example return true 
e.g.
{
    "name" : mkj123 mk
}

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;    
/**
         * 
         * @param inputJosn
         * @return
         * @throws IOException 
         * @throws JsonParseException 
         * @throws JsonProcessingException
         */
        private static boolean isJsonValid(String inputJosn) throws JsonParseException, IOException  {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            mapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_READING_DUP_TREE_KEY);
            JsonFactory factory = mapper.getFactory();
            JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(inputJosn);
            JsonNode jsonObj = mapper.readTree(parser);
            System.out.println(jsonObj.toString());


            return true;
        }
```