# How to validate if the text input is JSON

Tags: angularjs

how to validate if the text input is JSON with angularjs or js? I just found a way to do this with angular 2

Comment: how about JSON.parse ?

Comment: I think you can find your answer in here [how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try)

Comment: here is another method using JSON.parse [how to test if a string is json or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804777/how-to-test-if-a-string-is-json-or-not)

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the Code for the Same:

```
let checkForJSON = (str) => {
    try {
       JSON.parse(str)
    } catch (err) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```