# jest ; how to test JSON.parse on a string will succeed

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, api, jestjs

I'm writing unit tests for an API.

If I do something like this :

```
const apiResponse:object = JSON.parse(body)
expect(apiResponse).toHaveProperty('error')
```

and the API is not returning JSON, then I get something like :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token p in JSON at position 0
>       at JSON.parse ()

Rather than getting an error in my tests, I'd like my test to fail.

What is a jest test I can do that says;
*is this string I've received parsable as valid JSON?*

Comment: Wrap it in a try/catch. There's no built in way of testing for json validity other than parsing it.

Comment: Expanding on @Adriani6  Change your code to wrap the parse in a Try/Catch, then return an exception when the parse fails, and then Jest can test for the exception with bad JSON, and another normal test for good JSON data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved this by adding a helper function I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46958615/8749874)

```
const isJSON = (str:string) => {
    try {
        const json = JSON.parse(str);
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(json).slice(8,-1) !== 'Object') {
        return false
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

and then am able to do this :

```
expect(isJSON(body)).toBe(true)
```

Comment: A parsed Json can consist of an array too.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [Jest's `.not.toThrow()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect.html#tothrowerror) to assert that the JSON parsing doesn't throw an error.

Here is an example I made that asserts an object can be parsed to valid JSON:

```
it("Produces metadata object that can be parsed to valid JSON", () => {
    const meta = articleMetaData(article);

    const parseJson = () => {
        const json = JSON.stringify(meta);
        JSON.parse(json);
    };

    expect(parseJson).not.toThrow();
});
```

If, for example, the object had a circular structure:

```
var obj = {
  a: "foo",
  b: obj
}
```

The test would fail:

```
Expected the function not to throw an error.
Instead, it threw:
    TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```