# Express BodyParser responds with Bad Request, Status 400?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node + Express

I use the following function to fetch some json from the server:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify( data ),
                success: cb
            });
```

About a 1/3 of the time Express fires back an error:

```
{ [Bad Request: Bad Request] name: 'Bad Request', status: 400 }
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: a stack trace would be nice

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like about 1/3 of the time, your data isn't an object or an array (but perhaps a single number or string, or `null` or `undefined`).

Even though `JSON.stringify` will handle those types, they don't produce a valid `JSON text` (as it's called in [RFC4627](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627), which defines the JSON format).

Comment: That was my first guess too however I have confirmed the data is valid JSON.  In fact I have hardcoded the string for testing purposes.

Comment: What other middleware are you using? Perhaps the 400 is generated by another middleware and the error isn't even related to the JSON you send it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you check your data before converting it into json, for whether it is already json or not. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313630/ajax-check-if-a-string-is-json) for checking json.